# What is the most hp you can have at level 20 with no wildshape?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, hit-points

I'm curious as to what the most HP you can have at level 20 is with no wildshape. All official sources allowed (no UA). My main question is max HP but I'm also curious about effective HP (so resistances, immunities, temp hp, etc)

Comment: Check out the linked question, let us know if it satisfies you. The criteria aren't *exactly* the same, but it does provide a solution without Wild Shape. Not sure how we feel about almost-duplicate optimization problems, I'll start a meta about it.

Comment: Also related: [What is the greatest amount of temporary hit points you can have at once?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112247)

Comment: I didn't see the dupe when I asked... Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Baleful Polymorph: You can be *anything*.

Comment: the invincibility spell gives infinite ehp but that's kinda cheating since it only lasts for 10 minutes and it's kinda cheap.